# Collectives communication:LogP model measuring benchmarks

Tags: mpi, openmpi

Now, i am measuring LogP model parameters ,and i want to find some benchmarks which measure its parameters.I find a LogP benchmark from this paper : "Fast Measurement of  Parameters for Message Passing Platforms " at this link:[benchmark](http://www.cs.vu.nl/albatross/).
But i can not access this server.
Do we have any other benchmarks ???

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [Intel MPI benchmarks](https://software.intel.com/en-us/articles/intel-mpi-benchmarks/) provide quite a variety of numbers on all sorts of p2p, collective and one-sided communication, that should gie you `L`. The [Sandia MPI Micro-Benchmark Suite](http://www.cs.sandia.gov/smb/) focuses on host overhead and real world message rates - I think you can derive `o` and `g` from that.

By the way, the website you mentioned is available on [web.archive.org](http://web.archive.org/web/20150816094903/http://www.cs.vu.nl/albatross/). The software is not, but you could of course just ask the author directly.

Answer (score 0):

The code is included in a different project the Communication Performance Modeling (CPM). The website and project can be found here: [CPM Website](https://hcl.ucd.ie/project/cpm). The code is in a folder called "logp_mpi-1.4".